# Netstandard Cannot convert from nuget System.Net.Http to GAC version

Tags: c#, azure-functions, dotnet-httpclient, .net-standard

I have a .NET core class library which builds a nuget package to the netstandard1.6. I want to use this library in a Azure function. But I'm getting this error, when I try to call a method inside the class library with the

```
using System.Net.Http;
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log) 
{
   return MyClassLib.Methode(req);
}
```

`error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage [D:\home\data\Functions\packages\nuget\System.Net.Http\4.1.0\ref\net46\System.Net.Http.dll]' to 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage [D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll]'`

I gues that D:\home\data\Functions\packages\nuget\System.Net.Http\4.1.0\ref\net46\System.Net.Http.dll is the dll coming form the  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },

I found similar issues with System.Net.Http: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9846
And I read something about:

> Examples of packages that are NOT fixed to 1.0
>   "System.Net.Http":"4.1.0-*"
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tutorials/managing-package-dependency-versions

Should I downgrade to netstandard 1.2 because the System.Net.Http version? But the I cannot support net46 anymore: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md

Is there a mismatch between netstandard and net46?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I have it working :) This what I did:

I added net46 as framework and moved "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0" only as dependencies for netstandard1.3. Because the System.Net.Http library which is inside the "NETStandard.Library".

MyClassLib:

```
"frameworks": {
"netstandard1.3": {
  "imports": [ "netcoreapp1.0" ],
  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "System.Xml.XmlSerializer": "4.0.11",
    "System.Xml.XmlDocument": "4.0.1",
    "System.Xml.XDocument": "4.0.11"
  }
},
"net46": {
  "frameworkAssemblies": {
    "System.Xml": "",
    "System.Xml.Linq": "",
    "System.Xml.Serialization": ""
  }
}
```

Add added "type": "build" in my depended reference projects.

```
"MyClassLib.Xml": {
  "target": "project",
  "type": "build"
},
```

Would be nice if somebody wrote a full tutorial with best practices for setting up modern class libraries.

Answer (score 1):

According to Azure Function's [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-reference-csharp/#package-management), it seems that the only supported framework at the moment is `net46`.

Comment: net46 is a supported platform by the netstandard. I downgrade the netstandard to 1.3 but still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, we officially support **up to** Netstandard 1.3. The `project.json` file should continue to use `net46` as the framework and compatible packages will be properly resolved (as I believe you have found). This is question is more related to .NET Standard than Azure Functions, so this would be a good source of information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library

Hope this helps!